# Calculations using loops based on age

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm am writing code which calculates an insurance premium up to the 65th birthday.

So far I've come up with this, but I'm getting tangled up in the loop:

```
function showQuote(bday,bmonth,byear)
{


    var DoB = new Date(byear,bmonth,bday) 
    var todayDate = new Date();
    todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
    todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth();
    todayDay = todayDate.getDate();
    var userAge;


    userAge = todayYear - byear;

    if(todayMonth < (bmonth - 1 ))
    {

    userAge--;

    }

    else if (((bmonth - 1) == todayMonth) && (todayDay < bday))

    {

    userAge--;

    }

document.getElementById("ageResult").innerHTML = "You are currently: " 
+ userAge;

var displayQuote = 0;

    for (Age = userAge; Age <= 65; Age--)

    {
    displayQuote = 500-(500*(65-Age)/100);
    return displayQuote;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is display the first 3 years and then the 65th year.

Comment: The `return displayQuote` inside your loop ends the function call the first time through the loop.  That would be an appropriate place for `if (userAge < 3 || userAge == 65) { /* code to display message */ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (Age = userAge; Age <= 65; Age--)

{
displayQuote = 500-(500*(65-Age)/100);
return displayQuote;
}
```

}

i believe your problems all lie in this part of your code.

1)Age-- is going to decrease so unless your user is older then 65 your loop will never end

2) when you use the return keyword it returns that value to whatever called it and exits the function

3) currently you are running the loop until the user reaches 65.

```
for (Age =userAge ; Age <= 65; Age++) {
   if ((Age<(userAge+3))|| (Age==65)){
       displayQuote = 500-(500*(65-Age)/100);
       alert(displayQuote);
   }
}
```

@Mike Samuel if you say Age<3 it will only give when the user is 0-2

```
 var Age = 65-userAge
 displayQuote = new Array(4);
 for (var i=0; i<3; i++)//first 3 years
     displayQuote[i] = 500-(500*(65+i)/100);
 displayQuote[3]= 500-(500*(65)/100);//65th year


    document.getElementById("quoteResult").innerHTML = "Your quote is: " + document.getElementById("quoteResult").innerHTML + "<br/> year 1 " + " : £" + displayQuote[0] + " " + "Year 2: £" + displayQuote[1] + " " + "Year 3: £" + displayQuote[2]+"<br />";
```

im not sure how you want to display when it is the 65th year. you would use displayQuote[3]; 
what you had before was reading the same variable 3 times. that is prob why you were having troubles.

Comment: Thanks @GreenGiant, I think I get it now. When I try to display the  values on the page, it only displays the amount for 65th year 3 times. Is there some way I can differentiate between the 4 results? is the best way to do it to put the values into an array?

Comment: how are you displaying the results? also you could make the display quote an array with a counter and increment the counter in the if statement. You could also try splitting the if statement into 2. One for the first 3 years and then and else if for the last year and just set the Age as 65. ill add the code above

Comment: ideally, I would like to display the results in a box on the page, but so far when I do, I get either undefined or the value for the 65th year (£500) 3 times...

Comment: You could try putting them all into one string by adding them, i figured you would want to be able to use the data calculated

Comment: This is how I have it displayed so far: `document.getElementById("quoteResult").innerHTML = "Your quote is: " + document.getElementById("quoteResult").innerHTML 
 + "<br/> year 1 " + " : £" + displayQuote + " " + "Year 2: £" + displayQuote + " " + "Year 3: £" 
 + displayQuote+"<br />";`

Comment: I edited my answer to work better. you are using the same variable to display the 3 different years that is prob why u are getting the same  value, and it would use the last value assigned to it

Comment: Yes I guess it only returns the final value if you don't specify. I just tried your code and got this `You are currently: 32 Your quote is: Your quote is:
year 1 : £undefined Year 2: £undefined Year 3: £undefined

year 1 : £undefined Year 2: £undefined Year 3: £undefined`.

Comment: Sry i realized there was a mistake in the code. there was an extra assignment to displayQuote that there shouldn't have been. i used this code for 30yrs and the output was 175 , 170, and 160.